# Deepest match first with XPath

Tags: xpath

I have a configuration file in xml, with increasing specificity. That is, the closest setting to some section is the setting that will be in effect, even if it is set on higher levels. A colleague suggested using XPath for this. But I'm not sure how it would work? I suppose I want to find the "deepest match" for the setting, then automatically backing out if there is no match.

For instance:

```
<Settings>
 <Foo>Bar</Foo>
 <Products>
  <Bar>Baz</Bar>
  <Product Name="Thingamabob">
   <Foo>Baz</Foo>
  </Product>
  <Product Name="Whizbang">
   <Bar>Foo</Bar>
  </Product>
 </Products>
</Settings>
```

Searching for the `Bar` setting for Thingamabob should return "Baz", but "Foo" on Whizbang. In the same way, `Foo` has a value of "Baz" for Thingamabob, but "Bar" on Whizbang.

Can this type of lookup be implemented with XPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching `Foo` on `Thingamabob` can be done like so

```
//*[@Name='Thingamabob']/ancestor-or-self::*/Foo
```

But this will give you two nodes, you want to obtain the node with the maximum `count(ancestor::*)` and then get its `text()` value

I don't know of a way to do max on a xml hierarchy like yours, use an external script to iterate over the node list given by the xpath to find the max depth, then grab its content.

EDIT:

You may be able to do this in XSLT 2.0, note I have not tested this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:function name="my:lookup">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:param name="arg"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[@Name='$name']/ancestor-or-self::*/$arg">
       <xsl:sort select="count(ancestor::*)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
       <xsl:if test="position()=1"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="my:lookup('Thingamabob','Foo')" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT 2:

I've also figure this should work in XPATH 2.0 but I've not tested it

```
//*[@Name='Thingamabob']/ancestor-or-self::*/Foo[count(ancestor::*) >= //*[@Name='Thingamabob']/ancestor-or-self::*/Foo/count(ancestor::*)]/text()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know for certain that <Bar> will precede <Product>, you could do it with this:

```
//Product[@Name='Thingamabob']/preceding-sibling::Bar|//Product[@Name='Thingamabob']/Bar
```

Comment: Well, I don't. As you see in the Whizbang example, `Bar` may occur within `Product`

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that.  I updated the xpath to include child Bar elements.  I also added "//" to the beginning, which is usually frowned upon, but it sounds like your schema is pretty loose.